# Can I draw this conclusion about invertibility of a function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, inverse, inverse-function

Suppose we have a smooth homeomorphism $f:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Df_p\neq 0$ for any $p$. Can we conclude that $f^{-1}$ is smooth, in these conditions? I think so, because we can apply the Inverse Function Theorem and get a smooth inverse locally in each point of $U$. As smoothness is a local definition, we can conclude $f^{-1}$ is globally smooth. Is this true?

Comment: What do you mean by smooth here?

Comment: Do you really just want $Df_p \neq 0$? Or do you actually want $Df_p$ invertible?

Comment: You might want to assume that the rank of $Df_p$ is $m$ at each point (so this means we need to say $m\le n$). Such a map is called an immersion. Then $A$ will be a submanifold and what you want is true.

Answer (score 1):

Define $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ by $f(x,y) = (x,y^3)$. This is a smooth map, and a homeomorphism. Observe the first partial $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is identically $1$, and so the Jacobian $Df$ never vanishes. However, this is not a diffeomorphism.

Comment: thank you! I think I'll have to go with the fact that my $f$ is an immersion!